# rails 3.2 a little sorting issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting

I am doing a searchable & sortable table. Actually I made it already apart from a couple of little details. I am sorting according to column names, but rails rejects recognize 1 of them. Now, thats my index.html.erb:

```
<table class="pretty" border="1" cellpadding="10">  
  <tr>
    <th><%= sortable("machine_name",       "M.Name")       %></th>
    <th><%= sortable("machine_brand",      "M.Brand")      %></th>
    <th><%= sortable("machine_model",      "M.Model")      %></th>
    <th><%= sortable("control_unit_brand", "C.Unit Brand") %></th>
    <th><%= sortable("control_unit_model", "C.Unit Model") %></th>
    <th><%= sortable("tool_axis_x",        "Axis X")       %></th>
    <th><%= sortable("tool_axis_y",        "Axis Y")       %></th>
    <th><%= sortable("tool_axis_z",        "Axis Z")       %></th>
    <th><%= sortable("rotary_axis_number", "R.Axis")       %></th>
    <th><%= sortable("linear_axis_number", "L.Axis")       %></th>
    <th><%= sortable "description"                         %></th>
    <th><%= sortable("name",               "Developer")    %></th>
    <th><%= sortable "updated_at"                          %></th>
  </tr>  

  <% for conf in @confs %>  
  <tr class="<%= cycle('oddrow', 'evenrow') -%>">
    <td><%= link_to conf.machine_name, conf %></td>
    <td><%= conf.machine_brand %></td>
    <td><%= conf.machine_model %></td>
    <td><%= conf.control_unit_brand %></td>
    <td><%= conf.control_unit_model %></td>
    <td><%= conf.tool_axis_x %></td>
    <td><%= conf.tool_axis_y %></td>
    <td><%= conf.tool_axis_z %></td>
    <td><%= conf.rotary_axis_number %></td>
    <td><%= conf.linear_axis_number %></td>
    <td><%= conf.description %></td>
    <td><%= conf.developer.name unless conf.developer_id.blank? %></td>
    <td><%= conf.updated_at %></td>
  </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

You can see how I am reaching model Conf's developer via developer_id and display its name. This part is working but, when it comes to sort it breaks! sortable action uses sort_column and this is it:

```
def sort_column
    ( (User.column_names.include?(params[:sort])) || (Conf.column_names.include?(params[:sort])) ) ? params[:sort] : "machine_name"
end
```

User is a model. Conf is another model. User has_many confs. Conf

```
belongs_to :developer, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'developer_id'
```

I think rails try to sort by name, but conf hasn't a name, gives error like

```
no such column: name: SELECT  "confs".* FROM "confs"
```

Sort_column defined with User's columns but I think rails behaves as User's columns are different than developers columns. How can I make rails to recognize developers columns?
**NOTE:** I tried Conf.developer.column_names.include?... but get an error "undefined method developer"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to add a 'developer_name' column when pulling the data:

```
@conf = your_current_logic.
          includes(:developer).                               # eager load your developer relation
          where('users.id IS NULL OR users.id IS NOT NULL').  # a meaningless filter to force a LEFT JOIN
          select("confs.*, users.name as developer_name")
```

Then you can reference 'developer_name' in your sortable column.

Alternatively, you can simply substitute `sortable('name', ...)` with `sortable('users.name', ...)`.  You may need to modify your `sort_column` logic to permit this convention.

One way to do that may be like this:

```
def sort_column
  if params[:sort] =~ /([^\.]+)\.([^\.]+)/ &&             # check if 'table.column' format is used
       %w(users confs).include? $1 &&                     # check if table name matches expectations
       $1.classify.constantize.column_names.include?($2)  # check if column is present in table's class
    params[:sort]    # 'table.column' format
  elsif Conf.column_names.include?(params[:sort]))        # if 'column' format is used, just check Conf class
    params[:sort]    # 'column' format
  else
    "machine_name"   # default sort column
  end
end
```

**UPDATE**

So using the second method, your data retrieval might look like this:

```
@confs = Conf.search(params[:search]).
              includes(:developer).
              where('users.id IS NULL OR users.id IS NOT NULL').
              order(sort_column + ' ' + sort_direction).
              paginate(:per_page => 10, :page => params[:page])
```

And any ambiguous columns (e.g. updated_at) should be qualified by table name:

```
<th><%= sortable "confs.updated_at"                      %></th>
```

And since you're going to be requiring qualified names, it sounds like the second method is the way to go.  Note that using `classify.constantize` to dynamically check the model class may have an element of risk - you can use a whitelist of available classes to mitigate this.  Updated to demonstrate this.

Comment: thanks for reply, your first suggestion gives error "no such column users.name as developer_name ...". making `sortable('users.name', ...)` gives no error, but doesn't sort, does nothing at all

Comment: @kalahari: For the first suggestion, it was assumed that you were joining the developer association as part of your logic. I see that may not be the case for you - updated to accomodate for this.  For the second suggestion, I mentioned that you'd need to modify sort_column method logic. More specifically to check for a 'name' within the 'users' column if you get a '.' delimited string for your sort params.

Comment: `def index
    @confs = Conf.search(params[:search]).order(sort_column + ' ' + sort_direction).paginate(:per_page => 10, :page => params[:page])
    end` this was my first index. after changed your 1st suggestion, it says `ambiguous column name: updated_at` and dont mad at me, I am a beginner learner for rails and your new 2nd way seems like alien work to me :) and tried now 2nd way and get `no such column: users.name`

Comment: @kalahari, the second method (or any method that tries to sort in the database) also _must_ contain a join on the users table so that it can be sorted.  You can use the same `includes` and `where` as the first method for this.  Re: ambiguous column name error, you'll get this if you refer to a column name that is present in more than one table unless you qualify it with the table name you want to use - updated to explain how to do this.